# Antenna polarization confusing

Tags: rf, antenna

[image]
How do we mount an antenna which is a meandered line shape, to be in vertical or horizontal polarization? Vertical pol means that the antenna mounted to vertically to the earth. I’m confused just because, for example, imagine that we have another printed patch antenna. When feeding thru Y axis, it becomes vertically polarized whereas if you feed thru X axis it becomes horizontally polarized. However, in the case of dipole antennas the current flows up and down thru the conductor, it is also said vertically polarized just because the current flows vertically to the earth ground. For a Yagi antenna, it flows parallel to the earth ground and called horizontally polarized. How should I think in such a meandered PCB antenna?

Comment: *Vertical pol means that the antenna mounted to vertically to the earth.* **No.** It means that the H-field component is vertical and stays that way. For that to be possible, the antenna must emit a field that is linearly polarized in the first place. Not every antenna does. For example, a helical antenna might emit a circularly polarized wave. There's no inherent guarantee any planar antenna is linearly polarized for every frequency you can operate it at. Don't assume it is!

Comment: *For a Yagi antenna, it flows parallel to the earth ground and called horizontally polarized.* **No.** You can mount a Yagi antenna any way you like to get vertical or horizontal polarization.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks, did you intend to mean E-field component instead of H-field component in your first comment?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I get it for a regularly shaped antennas, however, how would I know it in case of a meandered line. I mean, the trace first starts vertically and horizontally and vertically again like a zigzag. E-field component changes, am I thinking wrong:/ Do I need to think which way it follows most is the one that E-field stays most and can call it that vertical or horizontal polarization regarding the mostly stayed route.?

Comment: sorry, yes, E-field, not H-field.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For example, this embedded antenna includes its own ground , the outer conductor connected to it and the inner conductor connected to the antenna element (looks like zigzag), both on same layer. It says it’s linear polarization. How should I think to mount it to have vertical polarization?Should I always consider the earth ground for orientation?https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Siretta/ECHO1A-0.1M-IPEX-S-S-11?qs=QNEnbhJQKvaMq6dNpG9mGw%3D%3D&_gl=1*10ci61f*_ga*MTg0MDk5NDc0MS4xNjk5MDAyMjE2*_ga_15W4STQT4T*MTY5OTAwMjIxNi4xLjAuMTY5OTAwMjIxOC41OC4wLjA.

Comment: no, you should not. the rule is simple: E field constantly vertical -> vertical polarization. Nothing more, nothing less. Why are you trying to see a rule where there is none? And why are you asking this? the datasheet shows you that assumption "from position of ground follows polarization" to be wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I get it for a regularly shaped antennas, however, how would I know it in case of a meandered line.

Not at all from looking at it alone.

First of all, this seems to be a multi-band antenna, which will definitely behave differently for different frequencies. You'll need to expect polarization to be a function of frequency.

Then, complex antennas like these will usually not be a "pure" thing. You'll have to simulate them at all the frequencies you care about. That's why every such antenna comes with an extensive datasheet or with frequency-dependentent S-parameters & dual-pol pattern measurement files, answering exactly the question "how does my antenna radiate at a given frequency".

Now, from the dimension of this, and from the fact that my best guess is that this is a quad-band antenna (can't read the overcompressed silkscreen print, but I guess it agrees): This is probably for cellular applications. So, the device this is connected to might be mobile to begin with, and be subject to an urban multipath scenario, where little to none of the original polarization reaches the communication partner (the cell tower), and where at least one side of the communication employs MIMO/digital beamforming anyway. If that is right, then there's little motivation to give you a "purely" polarized antenna, anyways, and chances are this thing is mostly elliptically polarized at arbitrary angles. Again, differing on different frequencies.

The assumption "an antenna needs to be linearly polarized, and that linear polarization will be either vertical or horizontal" simply doesn't hold, and you should in general not assume it does.